# How to get total number of frames available in the Lottie Animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, lottie

I'm using random Lottie animation in my android app. I need to know the total number of frames used in the Lottie animation. depending upon the total frames, I want to loop the animation from 1st frame to the certain frame. for eg. If the Lottie file contains 60 frames then I want to perform the animation from 1 to any number < 60.

I'm using below dependency

```
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.2'
```

Comment: You can see the number of frames on the lottie page while you are viewing it.

Comment: the Lottie file is not downloaded from Lottie's website. It was sent by the design team.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can see the first and last frame counts in the json file. ip=first frame and op: last frame.

[image: example image]

Comment: +1. Note that in some Lottie files there are more than one `ip` and `op`. In this case the first  `ip` and `op` is the frames of all file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `addLottieOnCompositionLoadedListener` to get your lottie's `Composition`.

```
binding.myLottie.addLottieOnCompositionLoadedListener { composition ->
    val startFrame = composition.startFrame
    val endFrame = composition.endFrame
    //will log start/end frame values
    Log.d(TAG, "startFrame : $startFrame, endFrame : $endFrame") 
}
```

Then to specific part of an animation use `setMinAndMaxFrame()`

```
binding.myLottie.addLottieOnCompositionLoadedListener { composition ->
    val startFrame = composition.startFrame
    val endFrame = composition.endFrame
    if (maxFrame < endFrame) {
        binding.myLottie.setMinAndMaxFrame(1, maxFrame)
    }
}
```

read [here](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android?id=looping) more about looping a specific part of an animation.

Comment: getMaxFrame() returns 0.0

Comment: it is giving me an error LottieComposition.getStartFrame can only be called from within the same library (com.airbnb.android:lottie)

Comment: @VishalNaikawadi Can you post your code and xml of this part?