# How can I start a Lottie animation from a specific starting point?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift5, lottie

Let's say a `Lottie animation` has a total `duration` of 30 seconds.

How can I start the `animation` from the 15-second mark as opposed to the beginning mark?

I haven't found anything in the documentation regarding this.

I am presently attempting to do it with this code:

```
animationView.play()
animationView.isHidden = true 

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 15 { 
   animationView.isHidden = false 
}
```

The only issue would be the wait time between the user execution and the animation display.

Comment: Look : 
animationView.play(fromFrame:, toFrame:, withCompletion:) or 
animationView.play(fromProgress:, toProgress:, withCompletion:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look :

```swift
animationView.play(fromFrame:, toFrame:, withCompletion:)
```

or

```swift
animationView.play(fromProgress:, toProgress:, withCompletion:)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing this. If anyone needs to check the number of frames in a Lottie file, there's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040762/how-to-get-total-number-of-frames-available-in-the-lottie-animation